# I have two loops that are clashing

Tags: javascript, dom, loops

I have two loops that are controlling two pieces of functionality on the site I am developing. The second loop is voiding out the second and causing me to lose some vital functionality.  The two loops are as follows:

//LOOP 1

```
function showHide(d) {
    var onediv = document.getElementById(d);
    var divs = ['content1', 'content2', 'content3', 'content4', 'content5', 'content6', 'content7', 'content8'];
    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        if (onediv != document.getElementById(divs[i])) {
            document.getElementById(divs[i]).style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
    onediv.style.display = 'block';
}
```

// LOOP 2

```
function active(clickedLink) {
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName('A');
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        links[i].className = ''
    }
    clickedLink.className = 'active';
}
```

Anyways, essentially, these two loops control some hidden div's and the links that show those divs.

The one loop is a showHide loop to obviously show and hide the div's when clicked on or rolled over, and the other is a little loop to keep the active state of the links after clicked on (the active div link will have a background color)

The problem is that my layout wasn't ideal for the rollovers, so I removed them, no big deal right? Well now the click (click a link and it shows the div that was clicked) feature isn't working. These two loops have to be clashing, because when I delete the second loop (the function(active) one) the click feature starts working again.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="left-side-links">

            <ul>
                <li><a href="javascript:showHide('content1');" onclick="active(this); return false;" class="link" id="link1">Healthcare</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:showHide('content2');" onclick="active(this); return false;" class="link" id="link2">Pharmaceutical Retail</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:showHide('content3');" onclick="active(this); return false;" class="link" id="link3">Manufacturing</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:showHide('content4');" onclick="active(this); return false;" class="link" id="link4">Hospitality</a></li>
            </ul>


            </div>

            <div id="right-side-links">

            <ul>
                <li><a href="javascript:showHide('content5');" onclick="active(this); return false;" class="link" id="link5">Entertainment</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:showHide('content6');" onclick="active(this); return false;" class="link" id="link6">Financial Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:showHide('content7');" onclick="active(this); return false;" class="link" id="link7">Oil, Gas & Energy</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:showHide('content8');" onclick="active(this); return false;" class="link" id="link8">Education Government</a></li>
            </ul>

            </div>

            <div id="clear"></div>

            <div id="left-side-bottom">

                <img src="images/bottomright.png" alt="bottomright" width="" height=""/>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div id="right-side">   

            <div id="content1"><img src="images/cookie3.png" alt="cookie3" width="462" height=""/>

                <p>Plus 6’s extensive video rental options have just the solution for you.  When connected to our infrastructure, you will be linked to any standards based system worldwide.
                system is easy. Test 1  </p>
                <img src="images/Design1b.png" alt="Design1b" width="" height=""/>

            </div>

            <div id="content2"><img src="images/casinoimage5.png" alt="casinoimage5" width="462" height=""/>

                <p>Plus 6’s extensive video rental options have just the solution for you.  When connected to our infrastructure, you will be linked to any standards based system worldwide.
                system is easy. Test 2  </p>
                <img src="images/Design1b.png" alt="Design1b" width="" height=""/>

            </div>

            <div id="content3"><img src="images/FCF_Holidays.png" alt="FCF_Holidays" width="462" height=""/>

                <p>Plus 6’s extensive video rental options have just the solution for you.  When connected to our infrastructure, you will be linked to any standards based system worldwide.
                system is easy. Test3  </p>
                <img src="images/Design1b.png" alt="Design1b" width="" height=""/>

            </div>

            <div id="content4"><img src="images/mick21.png" alt="mick21" width="462" height=""/>

                <p>Plus 6’s extensive video rental options have just the solution for you.  When connected to our infrastructure, you will be linked to any standards based system worldwide.
                system is easy. Test4  </p>
                <img src="images/Design1b.png" alt="Design1b" width="" height=""/>

            </div>

            <div id="content5"><img src="images/cookie3.png" alt="cookie3" width="462" height=""/>

                <p>Plus 6’s extensive video rental options have just the solution for you.  When connected to our infrastructure, you will be linked to any standards based system worldwide.
                system is easy. Test5  </p>
                <img src="images/Design1b.png" alt="Design1b" width="" height=""/>

            </div>

            <div id="content6"><img src="images/casinoimage5.png" alt="casinoimage5" width="462" height=""/>

                <p>Plus 6’s extensive video rental options have just the solution for you.  When connected to our infrastructure, you will be linked to any standards based system worldwide.
                system is easy. Test 6  </p>
                <img src="images/Design1b.png" alt="Design1b" width="" height=""/>

            </div>

            <div id="content7"><img src="images/FCF_Holidays.png" alt="FCF_Holidays" width="462" height=""/>

                <p>Plus 6’s extensive video rental options have just the solution for you.  When connected to our infrastructure, you will be linked to any standards based system worldwide.
                system is easy. Test 7  </p>
                <img src="images/Design1b.png" alt="Design1b" width="" height=""/>

            </div>

            <div id="content8"><img src="images/mick21.png" alt="mick21" width="462" height=""/>

                <p>Plus 6’s extensive video rental options have just the solution for you.  When connected to our infrastructure, you will be linked to any standards based system worldwide.
                system is easy. Test 8   </p>
                <img src="images/Design1b.png" alt="Design1b" width="" height=""/>

            </div>

        </div>

        </div>
```

If you have any ideas, please let me know. I'm sure it's something stupid and easy, but I'm new to javascript so I don't even really know what to search to figure it out.

Thanks! 
Mike Legacy

Comment: 'The second loop is voiding out the second' .. typo?

Comment: Why are you using both the `href` and `onclick` attributes? Perhaps moving all of the desired functionality into the `onclick` handler would help you understand what is going on.

Comment: I am using the onclick handler to keep the active state background color and the href is supposed to perform the showHide action

@paislee Yes, the second loop is voiding out the FIRST loop, thank you.

Comment: @Ben, Also, the link has to have an HREF or it becomes unclickable. I tried to merge all the functionality into the onclick handler but it takes away the link's functionality itself.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried running your code in my browser.

I think that you need to make the following change:

```
<a href="javascript:showHide('content1');" onclick="active(this); return false; "class="link" id="link1">Healthcare</a>
```

**should instead be:**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="active(this); showHide('content1'); return false;" class="link" id="link1">Healthcare</a>
```

Please try making an analagous change for each link.  It doesn't make sense to use the `href` and `onclick` attributes at the same time.